# JQuery validate and checkboxes (Chrome/Safari)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0 to validate my styled forms. I've tested IE7/8/9, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. Everything is working fine, except for validation of checkboxes in Safari and Chrome. There is no errormessage or prevention of posting the form. Is there anything I can do, or is this an issue for Safari and Chrome?

Checkboxes:

```
<label class="checkbox" for="joingroupkey_1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox hiddeninput" value="1" id="joingroupkey_1" name="joingroupkey">
    <div class="checkbox styled"></div>
    Newsletter 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="joingroupkey_2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox hiddeninput" value="2" id="joingroupkey_2" name="joingroupkey">
    <div class="checkbox styled"></div>
    Newsletter 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="joingroupkey_3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox hiddeninput" value="3" id="joingroupkey_3" name="joingroupkey">
    <div class="checkbox styled"></div>
    Newsletter 3
</label>
```

Script:

```
$('#newsletter').validate({
    rules: {
        joingroupkey: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
        label.insertBefore(element);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you see the problem here? http://jsfiddle.net/LpAvu/

Comment: No, seemsto be working fine. To be honest I don't know jsFiddle, does it make any difference which browser I use?

Comment: No, but if the code is the same you *should* see the same problem in the fiddle in the problematic browsers.

Comment: is all other validation working fine or you have only check boxes in your form for input?

Comment: I've got some other inputs and wrapping divs inside the form, but otherwise it should be the same. I will try stripping everything else out and see what happens, as the link you posted was working with Safari.
And yeah, all other validation is working fine.

Comment: I've output only the simple form, but still no validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I found the answer to my question in one simple line of css:

**input,textarea,select {   -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none;}**

When I remove this line, validation is working.

I have to admit I don't know how this is affecting the script, I had to start at top of the generated html and work my way through the lines until I found the css causing the problems.

Comment: Ah. Were you using some kind of styling checkbox plugin? jQuery validate does not validate hidden fields by default, so I bet that's what it was.

Comment: Not using any styling plugin, the checkboxes is not hidden, but have an opacity set to 0. And they were validated in other browsers. But thank you for your inputs to this issue, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

One more css can stop the validation working for checkboxes in chrome and safari.( still in 2018 !!! )

```
width:0px;height:0px;
```